# Google Cloud Speech API returned "Quota exceeded"

Tags: google-cloud-speech

My desktop Python application transcribes large sets of speech samples (each speech sample duration is between 1 sec and 8 sec long) and for that I am using Google Cloud Speech API. I am aware of all the usage limitations mentioned in this [page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits) and certainly within the limits to make sure that I do not violate any of these conditions.

When I started the application for one of my set of speech samples, it was able to transcribe few of them and interrupted in the middle with this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
<HttpError 429 when requesting 
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize?alt=json returned 
"Quota exceeded.">
```

I searched on web with this error ID and found [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4) but I could not specifically relate it to the one that I am dealing with. Are there any other limitations with Google Cloud Speech API that I should be aware of?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You got rate limited by the Google Cloud API. Try waiting a bit and trying your request again.

Comment: My application have made 306 requests, but the limit per 100 seconds was 500 requests. Rate limits are mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits#request_limits)

Comment: Are you sure that your application doesn't double request or something along those lines? This is very hard to answer with just an error message.

Comment: I am positive that application does not do that. It transcribes one speech sample at a time and waits for Google to send the response back. And then it continues with the next speech sample.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter this problem. Try checking the quotas on your API Manager dashboard > Speech API > Quotas.

I've just found out that for a simple Asynchronous requests, my quota increased by 50 requests.

Comment: Do you use free trial ?